# Unix variables - The correct way

Tags: variables, unix, path

Is this the recommended way of writing  shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR_VERSION_NUMBER = "x.y"
cd /path/to/VAR_VERSION_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is correct way:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR_VERSION_NUMBER="1.3"
cd /path/to/file/${VAR_VERSION_NUMBER}/more/path
```

The things missing from your example:

1. Dollar sign ($) in front of variable name (VAR_VERSION_NUMBER).
2. There should be no space between variable name and equal sign (=) in assignment.
3. It is a good practice to surround variable name in curly braces, but it is not needed here.

Also note that once the script is over and shell exits, you will be back to the original directory you started in. The effect of `cd` command is limited to the shell you script is running in, not to the shell you are launching your script from.

Comment: Thanks! so if this path is intermediate, would it be cd /path/$VAR_PATH/? The reason I as is because the script runs without the dollar sign

Comment: It will be `cd /path/${VAR_PATH}/blah`. You need dollar sign, and you need curly braces if you are interpolating your variable inside a string.

Comment: Generally, ALL_CAPS variables are used only for UNIX system or vendor application information. Also, I would write `var_path=/path/to/dir; var_file="$var_path/filename" (or similar). (A very minor point ;-) ) Good luck to all.

Comment: You should also mention that the `=` may not be surrounded by spaces. You did it correctly in your answer, but you didn't mention the change. Also, since you pass it to `cd`, `"/path/to/a/directory"` would be more appropriate.